# Unique two columns in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm working with laravel 5.6 I have this table

```
users_groups table
```

with these columns `user_id` reference to `users` auto increment id and `group_id` reference to group auto increment id in `groups` table

Now I'm trying to validate the entry of data to be unique value for both columns together, but  it can't be `user_id` and `group_id` the same in the table. 
I found this code and tried it:

```
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'user_id' => 'required|unique_with:users_groups,group_id',
        'group_id' => 'required|unique_with:users_groups,user_id',
    ]);
```

It gave me this error:

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUniqueWith does not exist.

Any help please?

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a `unique_with` validation rule. Are you using some sort of third-party package for this rule, like https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator ?

Comment: no i dont i just tried that

Comment: will im trying  to found any validation for tow column together

Comment: Try the package I linked, then. Again, there's no `unique_with` validation rule in Laravel by default, so that's why you get the error.

Comment: i know its gone when i remove unique_with i need anything help me to do the validation without using unique_with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to validate against a table in a database is to use `unique:table name,column`

for your case it should be

```
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'user_id' => 'required|unique:users_groups,group_id',
    'group_id' => 'required|unique:users_groups,user_id',
]);
```

see [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: i tried this i cant add same user id with many  group id or group id with many user is

Comment: As per the vallidation the user_id or group_id has to be unique, It will have only one entry in the table. If you want to have multiple entries remove the unique validation flag

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
// Haven't tried this code, but it should be pretty close to what you're looking for
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'user_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users_groups')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('group_id', $request->group_id);
        })
    ],
    'group_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users_groups')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
        })
     ]
]);
```

Comment: Undefined variable: request

Comment: How does your controller method looks like?

Comment: change $request by \request()

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
      'user_id' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('users_groups')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('group_id', \request()->input('group_id'));
            })
        ],
      'group_id' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('users_groups')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('user_id', \request()->input('user_id'));
                })
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers are correct and code can still be simplified

```
'user_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users_groups')->where('group_id', request('group_id'))
    ],
  'group_id' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('users_groups')->where('user_id', request('user_id'))
        ],
```